# How to cancel and set AlarmManager at the same time

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, intentservice

What I am doing at the moment is, using `AlarmManager.SetAlarm(context)` to enable and `AlarmManager.CancelAlarm(context)` to cancel it. I am using it with an `IntentService`.

What I want to do is cancel the alarm from triggered `IntentService` and then set it again such as:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    FooAlarmManager foo = new FooAlarmManager();
    foo.CancelAlarm(FooClass.this);
    //Do some stuff
    foo.SetAlarm(FooClass.this);
}
```

Why I am doing this? Because within `FooAlarmManager` I am getting the time from a static class such as:

```
public void SetAlarm(Context context) {
        Integer minutes = StaticValuePass.getMins();
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, FooAlarmManager.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * minutes*60, pi);
}
```

And I am setting the value of time from `onHandleIntent()`. So basically I am doing some check within `onHandleIntent()` and determining when should be the next alarm.

Unfortunetely, my code above doesn't work, the reason is when you use `setAlarm()` it actually invokes `onHandleIntent()` immediately.

So I have two questions in this case,
1) Can I prevent `setAlarm()` to invoke `onHandleIntent()` when it is firstly created?

2) (Assuming the above doesn't work) How can I change the alarm interval time?

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter, currently `System.currentTimeMillis()`, is the time at which you want the repeating alarm to first go off. So setting it to the current time will trigger the alarm immediately. Setting it to `System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * minutes * 60)` should fix your problem.

Please refer to the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,+long,+long,+android.app.PendingIntent)